# Does FCM send notifications to mobile and web at the same time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The logic of my project is that I have to send notifications from admin panel to users in web and mobile app at the same time! another meaning:

When the admin send a notification to John Doe   I need John to receive the notification on website and mobile app at the same time!

Does FCM can do that ? or I have to send notifications for mobile app and do another thing for web to web which is admin to user on web??

Answer (score 1):

FCM does not guarantee the timing of the receipt of messages.  If you send two messages, they will very *likely* end up on the devices at *about* the same time, but there is no guarantee that they will.  Also consider that one of the devices might not even be on at the time the message is sent - that message simply will not arrive until the device is turned on again.

But you can certainly write code to send as many messages as you need to as many devices as you want, and simply accept the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. That's the nice thing about Firebase services, so that you don't have to write entirely different code for the same functionality for each platform separately.

Comment: Did you try something like that before ? because @Doug says  there is no guarantee!

Comment: Yes, I've made apps that use FCM. I haven't compared second-to-second, but I also haven't encountered any issue till date.
PS: Doug's YT videos on the Firebase channel are awesome and definitely worth watching!